# How do i make a mobile site readable?

Tags: browser, mobile, mobile-website, ipod

I cant really link the site i am talking about here (or paste css). But what do i need to do to make the site readable on an ipod touch? and other mobile device?

I used width: 100% (and i think i tested with 95%) and removed any widths with pixels. What happens is the width fits however the text is not readable. You need to zoom in + scroll to read. I believe on another device i had to scroll but that screen was really tiny and i think i make a css mistake somewhere.

Anyways whats the proper way to have text readable on a mobile device or at least ipod touch?

Comment: See about viewport metatag here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844020/way-to-do-content-adaptation-to-mobile

Answer (score 1):

did you add Doctype correctly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
```